# How does a seed germinate in a plastic bag and how long before it start dying

Tags: germination, repotting

I have successfully germinated mango seed in what was impossible to think. It has sprung beautiful. I had placed it within wet kitchen towel. I was surprised and wanted to find out how without soil and sunlight (natural things) it grow?

I am thinking of moving it out to garden but I read somewhere it should be moved a pot filled with soil. How long do I have before it start decaying?

[image: one week old pic]
[image: today pic]

Comment: Wow, how long did it take to grow that big?

Comment: I placed the seed on 30th May, so one month.

Comment: In what temperature and climate do you live?